# Android TextView: how can I change layout dynamically as text is typed

Tags: android, imageview, dynamiclayout

I need to set a button to "visible" or "gone" dynamically as user types on a TextView field. By using the statement below, I have been able to accomplish it when Enter is pressed, but that would be great if the button becomes visible or gone immediately as the user types or deletes the text content.
Any suggestion?

```kotlin
binding.textField.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event -> 
    if (v.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        binding.button.visibility = View.GONE
    } else{
        binding.button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    return@setOnEditorActionListener true
}
```

Thank you in advance for your attention! 
Rodrigo Tomaz.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addTextChangedListener` on your EditText.

Like this:

```
binding.textField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if (editable.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
               binding.button.visibility = View.GONE
            } else{
               binding.button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

        }
    });
```

Hope that help :)

Comment: Hello @Ryann, 
Thank you very much for your help. And I'm sorry for the delayed feedback.
Since I'm a beginner on both Android and Kotlin, it took me a little while to implement your suggestion. 
Turns out that Kotlin offers simplified access to the override functions. I have posted the final implementation below, for everybody's information.
Thank you again for your support!

Answer (score 0):

you should add textchangelistner to your editext and hide button on text change

```
binding.textField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

       @Override    
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override    
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {
        binding.button.visibility = View.GONE
       }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin offers a simplified access to the override functions. Here's my final (working) implementation, fyi:

```
binding.textField.doAfterTextChanged { text: Editable? ->
    if (text.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        binding.button.visibility = View.GONE
    } else{
        binding.button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```